# Kubernetes HTTP health check fails with `http: server gave HTTP response to HTTPS client`

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-health-check

This occurred after I did a:

```
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} !https
    RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301,NE]
```

In apache which in effect does a 301 redirect based on a HTTP header.

Demonstarted with this curl:

```
curl -vk -H 'Host: example.com' 172.17.0.2/api/v1/ping
* Expire in 0 ms for 6 (transfer 0x1af6470)
*   Trying 172.17.0.2...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Expire in 200 ms for 4 (transfer 0x1af6470)
* Connected to 172.17.0.2 (172.17.0.2) port 80 (#0)
> GET /api/v1/ping HTTP/1.1
> Host: example.com
> User-Agent: curl/7.64.0
> Accept: */*
> 
< HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
< Date: Fri, 26 Jul 2019 18:14:09 GMT
< Server: Apache/2.4.38 (Debian)
< Location: https://example.com/api/v1/ping
< Content-Length: 239
< Content-Type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1
< 
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//IETF//DTD HTML 2.0//EN">
<html><head>
<title>301 Moved Permanently</title>
</head><body>
<h1>Moved Permanently</h1>
<p>The document has moved <a href="https://example.com/api/v1/ping">here</a>.</p>
</body></html>
* Connection #0 to host 172.17.0.2 left intact
```

Why is this pod failing on this error?

```
  Warning  Unhealthy  99m (x7 over 100m)  kubelet, minikube  Readiness probe failed: Get https://172.17.0.9:80/api/v1/ping: http: server gave HTTP response to HTTPS client
```

Comment: It will help to see the probe's definition. In particular, `scheme` (defaults to `http`) and `httpHeaders`, if configured. Otherwise, per the docs (https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/configure-liveness-readiness-probes/#define-a-liveness-http-request): 
"...Any code greater than or equal to 200 and less than 400 indicates success. Any other code indicates failure". The test with `curl`, btw, doesn't specify a scheme in the URL so it defaults to `http`.

Answer (score 2):

Probably it's just seeing the 301 redirect to https... The error is a a bit misleading as it does not even attempt a HTTPS request... I'd assume it would just not follow the 301 and instead fail on not returning a 200...

Answer (score 0):

I just had this error now. And I was able to demonstrate that the problem is indeed that. The error message is misleading. The true error is that the health check endpoint is returning code 301.
Changing the readiness probe configuration from HTTP to HTTPS does not help.
Solution is to fix the software that runs on the pod and get it to respond http code 200 in the health check endpoint.
One can use Chris' query to check the http return code, or maybe this other query, that responds with the http return code and nothing else:

```
curl -s -o /dev/null -w "%{http_code}" <address>
```